# How to fix 'Using Spring AOP,I want to change the return value,but the return Class is not my method return'

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am useing Spring AOP to change the return value.But I found that the in the @Around function return value is not the method return value.How to fix the problem?

Controller

```
Page<Object> page = PageHelper.startPage(pageNo, pageSize, true);
    CallRecordEntity callRecordParam = new CallRecordEntity();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(callRecordVO, callRecordParam);
    callRecordParam.setEnterpriseId(ThreadCacheMgr.getEntId());
    List<CallRecordEntity> list = callRecordService.callList(callRecordParam);
```

Service

```
  @Override
  @SensitiveInfo(SensitiveInfoType.CALL_RECORD)
  public List<CallRecordEntity> callList(CallRecordEntity callRecordEntity) {

}
```

```
  @Pointcut("@annotation(com.zhexinit.aicc.common.annotation.SensitiveInfo)")
  public void sensitiveInfoAspect() {

  }

 @Around("sensitiveInfoAspect()")
  public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    UserCacheVO userCacheVO = (UserCacheVO) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
        .getPrincipal();
    Object ret = point.proceed();
    Signature signature = point.getSignature();
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) signature;
    Method targetMethod = methodSignature.getMethod();
    System.out.println("classname:" + targetMethod.getDeclaringClass().getName());
    System.out.println("superclass:" + targetMethod.getDeclaringClass().getSuperclass().getName());
    System.out.println("isinterface:" + targetMethod.getDeclaringClass().isInterface());
    System.out.println("target:" + point.getTarget().getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("proxy:" + point.getThis().getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("method:" + targetMethod.getName());
    System.out.println("methodReturnType:" + targetMethod.getReturnType().getName());
    System.out.println("return value:" + ret.getClass().getName());
    return ret;
  }
```

I expect the ret.getClass().getName() to be List,but the return value is Page in the controller

Comment: That simply isn't possible and the debugging you are looking at isn't belonging to the code you are showing here.

Comment: when I delete Page<Object> page = PageHelper.startPage(pageNo, pageSize, true); The answer is correct.

Comment: The question is hard to understand, the question title completely incomprehensible. Would you please update the question to explain in more detail what the problem is? Ideally, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As of now I cannot see how and where you change the return value in your aspect (you just return the original value), there is no application code reproducing the problem and you don't show any log output explaining the problem.